# How can I improve my English WordPress site's position in google.es (for Spain)?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, wordpress, search-results

For a long time I've been struggling with my WordPress homepage.

At the moment I live in Switzerland and my site is just in English. You can find my website easily in Google in all the countries (e.g., Switzerland, Germany, Mexico, England, Peru, etc...). In Switzerland it's the first result, in the other countries it's in the first page of results. So until now I am OK with it.

But unfortunately in the Spanish results of the desktop version of Google, it appears 12 or 13 in the results list, which is the second page. But in the mobile site, it appears in the first page of results.

The site's name is my own name, and there are some people with the same name as me in Spain. Now it is like this: `www.surname-name.com`. Should I use `www.surnamename.com`? I own that domain too.

What should I implement in order to make my site more visible in Spain (i.e., in Spanish language)? Before I spend hours and money on some solution, I would like to know which is the best strategy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Comment: @MySiteIGuess Is your site translated into Spanish? Is any part of it written or targeted for an audience in Spain? If so, are you using [geotargeted URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en) to indicate that to Google? Sites that are more relevant to visitors in Spain will be ranked higher there.